# Should the title still be Computer Science Educators?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I believe that they're aren't that many people out there who are interested in a site that is only for Computer Science Educators. Personally, I'm a Java student, and my interest rate in this site is dropping exponentially. I think the site should be more open and broad so that more users will be interested in joining. I'm not sure about this, but if we can, we should change the site name(if enough interest) to something that appeals to all users interested in Comp Science, not just the teachers. Hope this works out.

Comment: What else do you want to include?

Comment: You mean, like [comp sci](https://cs.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: I'm not good at naming things, but the title should change to be something more broad like Computer Science Fans..

Comment: @KrishnanshuGupta I think the misunderstanding here is that this site **is** for teachers and educators (or those interested in education). Computer Science Fans wouldn't encapsulate what this site is actually **about**, and would just confuse people more. In a way, this site *shouldn't* appeal to anyone interested in Computer Science, because it's a site about teaching.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm a little perplexed by this topic. The fact that we even made it to private beta says quite a bit about the number of people interested in the site. We are merely scratching the surface right now of what this community can become. I also don't think "open and broad" is a goal; we want focused, researched, objective, and precise.

That's great that you are a student studying Java. Might I suggest following [java](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/java) on Stack Overflow, Code Review, Programming Puzzles & Code Golf, etc? Those sites would be more tailored to your particular interests.

The only semantic change I could toy with is Computer Science Education v. Educators. This came up in another thread, but with the growing access to CS education online and through bootcamps, many people are taking a non-traditional path to pursue CS. The self-learning approach should have a home somewhere. Maybe it is simply SO, but we here might be able to offer pedagogical insight along side the programming experience. It makes sense to keep it as is alongside Math Educators, but that discipline does not have the same kind of self-learner demographic (unless there are multivariable calculus bootcamps I don't know of).

Answer (score 8):

I'm afraid I don't really understand the question.

> we should change the site name (if enough interest) to something that appeals to all users interested in Comp Science, not just the teachers.

This site is meant for the teachers, and is therefore meant to be primarily interesting to teachers.

For general questions about Computer Science, please vist [Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions).